# mysql command does not execute mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, terminal, path, zshrc

The path to my bin folder with mysql:

> usr/local/mysql/bin

Here is my zshrc bash config:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/leon/bin/subl"
export PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

When I type `mysql` I get the following

[image]

---

Commands run:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/leongaban/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

which mysql
mysql not found

mysql --help
zsh: command not found: mysql

sudo find / -name mysql
Password:
/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysql

ps -ef | grep mysql
   74    96     1   0 11:18AM ??         0:02.90 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid --port=3307
  501 16302  9174   0  1:27PM ttys001    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn mysql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PATH was correct, however it was getting overridden by a `PATH` var lower in my [.zshrc](http://www.zsh.org/) file

```
# User configuration
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
```

After commenting out that line, mysql works again.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few commands that might help determine more about the problem:

> echo $PATH
>
> which mysql
>
> mysql --help
>
> find / -name mysql
>
> ps -ef | grep mysql

If you still have no clue you might post the output to those commands here. Also to paraphrase Alex Trebek, please phrase your post in the form of a question. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: ah thanks, will try those in a bit and update my title

Comment: Also helpful to do a 'long listing' of the directory using 'ls -la'

Comment: Heya I updated my Question with the commands you posted and the results I got

Comment: Figured it out, there was another `PATH` variable overriding my config, lower in my .zshrc default settings

Comment: @Leon - looks like your first value for PATH is not getting appended properly to the PATH that is exported. You might try adding everything to the same PATH listing. Also, I don't see the point in exporting PATH twice, so you might try removing the first 'export' if you decide to stick with two lines.

Comment: Oops, didn't refresh there. Glad you found the problem!

Comment: Yeah I moved it all into 1 PATH `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/leon/bin/subl:/usr/local/bin/fab"`